# SwiftUI: How can I detect if two views are intersecting each other?

Tags: view, swiftui, frame, intersection

One view is intersecting the other one. How could we detect this intersection in SwiftUI?

In Swift I would reach this with a few lines of code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let a = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 150, height: 150))
    a.backgroundColor = .purple
    view.addSubview(a)

    let b = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 150, height: 150))
    b.backgroundColor = .orange
    view.addSubview(b)

    if a.frame.intersects(b.frame) {
        print("yes!")
    } else {
        print("no intersection!")
    }

  }

}
```

Obviously, it is not relevant for the SwiftUI: we have another concept of frames here. What could work instead? Has somebody an idea?

[image]

**Update:**

Many thanks for [user3441734](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3441734/user3441734) and [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) for their help and suggestions!
Here is my attempt to solve the problem, using array of rectangles:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var rect = CGRect()
@State var aRects = [CGRect]()


var body: some View {

    VStack {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                  .frame(width: 150, height: 300)
                  .foregroundColor(.purple)
                  .background(self.rectReader(self.$rect))
                  HStack {
                      Spacer()
                      Spacer()
                      Spacer()
                      Rectangle()
                          .frame(width: 150, height: 180)
                          .foregroundColor(.pink)
                         .background(self.rectReader(self.$rect))
                      Spacer()
                  }
            }

        Button(action: {
             //print("aRects: \(self.aRects)")
             self.checkIntersection()
         }){
            Text("Check Intersection!")
         }
    }



}


// fill array of rects here
func rectReader(_ binding: Binding<CGRect>) -> some View {
    return GeometryReader { (geometry) -> AnyView in
        let rect = geometry.frame(in: .global)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            binding.wrappedValue = rect
            print("rect: \(self.rect)")
            self.aRects.append(self.rect)
        }
        return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.clear))
    }
}

func checkIntersection() {
    if aRects.count == 2 {
        if self.aRects[0].intersects(self.aRects[1]) {
            print("yes!")
        } else {
            print("no!")
        }
    }
}

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Many. Did you try anything? At least [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+view+frame)?

Comment: I read a lot of stuff about geometry reader and so on and haven't found a simple way to do it. Sorry; if my question seems to be stupid.

Comment: @Asperi please see my answer :-) especially the last part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your question is not stupid at all!**

It seems to be easy

1. read frame of first View (in global coordinates) and save it in preferences
2. read frame of second View (in global coordinates) and save it in preferences
3. calculate intersection when preferences changed

create our preference key structure is easy, it was already explained at this web site before (use search for more details :-))

```
struct Sizes: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [CGRect]
    static var defaultValue: [CGRect] = []

    static func reduce(value: inout [CGRect], nextValue: () -> [CGRect]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}
```

using GeometryReader in background View modifier was already explained

```
struct SizeReader: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear
            .preference(key: Sizes.self, value: [proxy.frame(in: .global)])
        }
    }
}
```

and now we can use it to save frame rectangles in our Sizes preference key

```
RectView(color: .pink).background(SizeReader())
```

What about our RectView ? To demonstrate how our "easy solution" works imagine that somebody create it with random size and random alignment

```
struct RectView: View {
    let color: Color
    let size = CGFloat(Int.random(in: 50 ... 200))
    var body: some View {
        color.frame(width: size, height: size)
            .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) {
                CGFloat.random(in: 0 ..< $0.width)
            }
            .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) {
                CGFloat.random(in: 0 ..< $0.width)
            }
    }
}
```

so far, so good, we are ready to check our "easy solution"

Lets finish our project with

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var id = UUID()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.black
                RectView(color: .pink)
                    .background(SizeReader())
                RectView(color: .yellow)
                    .background(SizeReader())
                    .blendMode(.difference)
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(Sizes.self) { (value) in
                let intersection = value[0].intersection(value[1])
                print(value[0])
                print(value[1])
                print(intersection)
                print()
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                self.id = UUID()
            }
            Text("paceholder").id(id)
        }
    }
}
```

Run it and each time you click the black part of the screen you see two randomly sized and positioned rectangles and in the debug window printout of values ​​of our interest.

[image]

**WARNING** check the printout and you'll see that something if wrong!

**The code is buggy example and I put it here to demonstrate, that your question is not stupid at all! There is a lot of thinks to understand about SwiftUI layout and how it works behind the scene.**

*I hope, somebody clever will try to explain what's wrong and will guide us on how to make it functional, all experts are welcome! Please don't change RectView, think that it is some build-in SwiftUI component*

Comment: user3441734, thank you for this suggestion and explanations! It was a real help for me to start from this point and go further. Could you look at my update in the post please? I tried to use array of rects instead of preference key. It seems to work and has less code, but I would be very glad to have your opinion on it.

Comment: @Roman preferenceKey approach is the proper way and once you understand how it works, it is easy to use. see https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/ and next parts . my example demonstrate, that bounding box and visual appearance could be totally different.

Comment: Yes, I see this difference, thank you. But would you accept a usage of array, too?

Comment: @Roman :-) you have to like it! the asynchronous part of your code works and time to time I use similar solutions. you have to understand that it is very fragile and could stop to work in future. Using preferences is well documented and solid solution which is very similar to the way SwiftUI use to layout all UI components.

Comment: @Roman I have a hint for you to solve the bug in my example. It is build in RectView and it also demonstrate why asynchronous approach is fragile :-) (and could be very hard to find)