# Referencing Views created for structs

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am looking for advice around how to proceed with a problem:

I currently create an array of structs in my model - which I then use to create a set of Views which are laid out manually. An important part of the project is finding out which views are neighbouring which.

So my question is this - what is the best way to link the struct and the view - so that I can iterate through them and find overlapping views?

As requested : below is the code for creating the Views (HexagonViews)

```
var body: some View
{
    GeometryReader {fullScreen in
        VStack()
        {
            HStack()
            {
                ForEach(viewModel.dice){dice in
                    DiceView(dice: dice).onTapGesture(perform: {
                        viewModel.rollDice()
                    })
                }
            }
            VStack()
            {
                ForEach(viewModel.players){player in
                    playerView(player: player).font(Font.system(size:min(fullScreen.size.width, fullScreen.size.height)*0.1))
                }
            }
            
            let smallSide = min(fullScreen.size.width, fullScreen.size.height)/8
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true)
            {
                GeometryReader {scrollViewGeometry in
                    ForEach(viewModel.hexagons){hexagon in
                        let hexagonFrame = getFrameFor(hexagon: hexagon, minWidth: smallSide)
                        let colorArray = getColorsFor(hexagon: hexagon)
                        ZStack()
                        {
                            let thisIndex = hexagon.id
                            HexagonView(strokeColor: colorArray[0]).onTapGesture(perform: {
                                viewModel.chooseHexagon(hexagon: hexagon)
                            })
                            .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(hexagon.isSelected ? 360 : 0))
                            .animation(.linear(duration: 1.0))
                            
                            Text(String(thisIndex+1)).font(Font.system(size: hexagonFrame.size.width * fontScalingFactor)).foregroundColor(colorArray[1])
                                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                    viewModel.chooseHexagon(hexagon: hexagon)
                                })
                                .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.2, height: 1.2))
                                .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(hexagon.isSelected ? 360 : 0))
                                .animation(.linear(duration: 1.0))
                        }
                        .position(x: hexagonFrame.origin.x, y: scrollViewGeometry.size.height - (hexagonFrame.size.height/2) - hexagonFrame.origin.y)
                        .frame(width: hexagonFrame.size.width, height: hexagonFrame.size.height, alignment:.center)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You gotta show some code

Comment: What do you mean by `find overlapping views` and why they would overlap?

Comment: The views contain hexagons, which are packed together in a certain way - so the neighbouring views overlap. The game ends once there is a path across the views - so we need to see which views are next to each other.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should base all your logic (e.g. determining neighboring views) on the data - not on the views themselves. The views just reflect the data. Unless the views are moved by the user and you need to read their actual coordinates, then take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407125/swiftui-how-can-i-detect-if-two-views-are-intersecting-each-other) for reference